# How to convert a large binary (10000k bits) to base 3 or base 31?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math, bit

How can I convert a large binary (10k bits) to a base 3 or a base 31 number?
I know that for base 16 I can convert the number by taking 4 bytes chunks from my original number and this works well. But for base 3 or 31 is this even possible, since they are not a factor of 2?

## Edit

I tried to simplify the problem above, but for clarity think that there is a binary stream of 100MB, and you need to convert it in a stream that would be interpreted base 31.

Thanks for the answers so far.

Comment: [binary to base 31 conversion tool](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/binary-to-base-31-conversion.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a number from base 10 to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563998/convert-a-number-from-base-10-to-n)

Comment: base 10 to N is simple problem, and different than what I have asked.

Comment: Which is it, 10 kilobits or 10 megabits?

Comment: The problem is under-specified (i.e. there's not enough information to give an answer).  Is the entire bit stream to be treated as a single binary number or is it to be split into units of a certain length and then encoded?

Comment: @JimGarrison I would guess the former, or why even ask it (mentioning the 10000k bits)?

Comment: I _wouldn't_ assume either option.  The OP's clarification does not answer the question.

Comment: _"binary stream of 100MB"_ -- so now we have THREE different numbers for the size of the stream.  Again, is the order of magnitude 10,000 bits, 10,000,000 bits, 100,000,000 bits or 800,000,000 bits?  Please [edit] your question and clean it up to give one consistent number for the order of magnitude of the problem.

Comment: _"you need to convert it in a stream that would be interpreted base 31"_  -- Does this mean that the entire stream is to be interpreted as a ***single*** binary integer consisting of that many bits?  Even with the smallest quantity (10,000) that number is 2^10000 or roughly 10^3300, vastly larger than the number of subatomic particles in the entire universe.  Really?  Are you sure you understand the problem to be solved?  Next question: Is the bit stream little-endian or big-endian?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Java and C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a streaming fashion. For example, if the streams are big-endian, then you'll need to wait until the last bit in the input to distinguish between 31^100001 and (31^100001 - 1), and this difference affects the first bit of the output.

Comment: that's a good point @sasmith

Answer (score -1):

It might not be the fastest, most efficient way to get the job done, but a very easy approach would be to use Java's BigInteger class.

```
(new BigInteger(hugeBinaryNumberAsString, 2)).toString(3)
```